# Java calling method and using ternary operator and assign in the parameters?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, ternary, method-call

I was reviewing some code and I came across this:

```
 public static doSomething(String myString, String myString2) {
        //Stuff
 }

 public static doAnotherThing(String myString) {
      return doSomething(myString = myString != null ? myString.toLowerCase(): myString, null)
 }
```

How is this working exactly?, I know the .toLowerCase resulting string is assigned to myString (yes I know bad practice since you are not supposed to reassign method parameters in fact they should be final), but I am not quite sure how does the method always receives the 2 parameters it needs.

I know how it works when myString is null or at least I think I do, since the ternary has myString, null, but I am not quite sure why it would go there when myString is not null?.

Comment: I just realized with the parenthesis like tskuzzy suggested this would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parenthesis to the rescue!

```
doSomething(myString = ( ( myString != null ) ? myString.toLowerCase() : myString ), null)
```

To understand this, you need to know two things:

- How the ternary operator works
- The fact that the assignment operator returns the thing it is assigning

Comment: Thank you, I know how both things works, what confused me was the : myString, null, but with the parenthesis it is clear. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

`doSomething` receives two parameters, both of which are strings. In `doAnotherThing`:

- The first parameter passed to `doSomething` is:

  - `null` if `myString` is `null`,
  - `myString.toLowerCase()` otherwise.
- The second parameter passed to `doSomething` is always `null`.

It might be clearer rewritten like this:

```
public static doAnotherThing(String myString)
{
    if (myString == null) return doSomething(null, null);
    else return doSomething(myString.toLowerCase(), null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused with the : domain, null - I was thinking myString was assigned this two values, but if we add parenthesis it is clear.

Comment: Is there any point in doing the assignment at all?, it works exactly the same removing the assignment.

Comment: @Oscar in this case, there is no point in doing the assignment.

Comment: Yes that is what I though, since this is called on a return, so even if there was code that used myString below, it would never run.

Answer (score 3):

Its just a more complicated version of:

```
public static doAnotherThing(String myString) 
{
  myString = myString != null ? myString.toLowerCase(): myString;
  return doSomething(myString, null) 
}
```

or even

```
public static doAnotherThing(String myString) 
{
  String s = myString;
  if (myString != null)
      s = myString.toLowerCase();
  return doSomething(s, null) 
}
```

Comment: The last one is verbose but the most easy to understand. It could also be writen without the local variable:  `if (myString != null)  myString  = myString.toLowerCase();  return doSomething(myString , null); `

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = myString != null ? myString.toLowerCase(): myString
```

This piece of code reassigns myString to be either myString.toLowerCase(), or it doesn't reassign it.  But the act of using the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned, thus you are essentially calling this:

```
//if myString != null
doSomething(myString.toLowerCase(), null);

//or if myString is null
doSomething(myString /*which is null*/, null);
```

You should also note that Strings are immutable, and that changing the value of myString in doAnotherThing(String) will not affect the String that was passed into the method.

Comment: Your last sentence is misleading. Yes, strings are immutable, but that does not mean that you can't alter a _reference_ to string.

Answer (score 1):

The code is confusing, but I am not sure what the problem is.  The result of an assignment is the value assigned.

This

```
 return doSomething(myString = myString != null ? myString.toLowerCase(): myString, null)
```

is the same as

```
 if(myString != null) myString = myString.toLowerCase();
 return doSomething(myString, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign into variable from ternary operator like so:

```
minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

More examples: 
http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018