# Referencing values passed in a function

Tags: java, function, syntax

I'm dealing with recursion and I was wondering if there is anyway to reference the variable (that is the result of a function) inside of another function. Here is the part of the code in question.

```
# functional way
ListNode x = maxNode(list.next);
if(list.info.compareTo(x.info) < 0) {
    return x;
}

# ideal way
if(list.info.compareTo(ListNode y = maxNode(list.next)) < 0) {
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511103/java-calling-method-and-using-ternary-operator-and-assign-in-the-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have the variable defined before hand and then set in the if statement

```
ListNode y;
if(list.info.compareTo((y = maxNode(list.next)).info) < 0)
    return y;
```

But it is a bit more readable to just set it before hand

```
ListNode y = maxNode(list.next);
if(list.info.compareTo(y.info))
    return y;
```

I would only suggest doing the setting in a checking statement for loops, as it can help with readability in that case

```
ListNode y = list;
while((y = y.next) != null)
    //dostuff
```

This form of while loop could also be more easily represented as a for loop

```
for(ListNode y = list; y != null; y = y.next)
    //dostuff
```